# ¿Por qué "hortera" es, en Madrid, el apodo del mancebo de ciertas tiendas de mercader?

Tags: vocabulario, etimología, españa

[**Hortera**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Kgf6i2k) es

> 1. adj. despect. coloq. Vulgar y de mal gusto. Apl. a pers., u. t. c. s.
> 2. f. Escudilla o cazuela de palo.
> 3. m. **En Madrid, apodo del mancebo de ciertas tiendas de mercader.**

Buscando en el NTLLE he encontrado que:

- la acepción original era la segunda (en el **Diccionario de Autoridades** viene recogido como "Escudilla de palo que ordinariamente usan los pobres ...")
- la tercera acepción aparece recogida en 1787 en el diccionario de **Terreros y Pando** ("llaman por desprecio a los Fatores, ó Mancebos de Mercaderes") y en 1802 en el Diccionario de la Lengua
- la primera acepción no aparece en el Diccionario de la Lengua hasta 1984

Se puede puede suponer que la primera acepción ("vulgar y de mal gusto") proceda de los usos y costumbres de los mancebos (tercera acepción) pero ¿cómo surgió, a partir de la acepción inicial ("escudilla de palo"), la referente a los mancebos y exclusivamente a los de Madrid?

Comment: Aquí aparecen dos versiones: http://etimologias.dechile.net/?hortera A mi la segunda me convence más pero no encuentro fuentes que la corroboren. Sobre todo veo más factible la segunda porque buscando en textos antiguos no parece que "hortera" tuviera la connotación negativa de hoy día.

Answer (score 8):

Parece ser que el uso de `hortera` como platillo o cuenco es de hecho el primer uso. [Escuelapedia](http://www.escuelapedia.com/etimologia/horteratomada-como-ejemplo-de-p/) explica parte del "envilecimiento o perversión del lenguaje" que ha sufrido la palabra `hortera`

> la palabra *hortera* ha recorrido un largo camino desde sus origenes **(documentada como *fortera* por primera vez en 1022)** hasta la actualidad, en una vida muy intensa que le ha proporcionado nada menos que tres significados conocidos, aparentemente desconectados entre si, aunque veremos que no tanto.

El primer significado es el de "fuente, bandeja o escudilla de metal o madera", algo que se usaría tanto en una sacristía para guardar las hostias, como en la cocina una casa como en una rebotica para preparar recetas.

> es el primer uso el que dé la clave de su etimologia, supuestamente debida a la forma del latin vulgar *offertoria*, plural o femenino de la palabra latina eclesiástica *offertorium*, con el valor de ‘patena para la hostia’

La web explica que la palabra fue evolucionando (usándose en otros ambientes) desde el platito para la hostia a la rebotica (tiendas)

> Asimismo, el uso de las horteras por parte de los mancebos de las reboticas (auténticos pinches de la farmacia) acabó por contaminar a sus más frecuentes usuarios, de manera que, poco a poco, **la persona tomó el nombre (y casi se lo quitó al utensilio)**.

Así que la palabra pasó de designar al objeto para designar a la persona (el ayudante de tienda o rebotica).

La web sigue explicando cómo el uso de `hortera` (un insulto cargado de clasismo, o de cierto complejo de superioridad del insultador sobre el insultado) pasó a designar a alguien que pretende vestir bien (como debían hacerlo los empleados de tiendas y reboticas) no por estatus social, sino por guardar las apariencias (debía ir bien vestido y mantener un lenguaje cuidado para que las clientas se encontraran a gusto) y de ahí la palabra pasó a designar a designar a un **falso señorito**, como explica [esta otra web](http://www.libertaddigital.com/opinion/amando-de-miguel/origenes-curiosos-de-algunas-palabras-62173/) (que por cierto, ya explicó el mismo origen en [este otro artículo](http://www.libertaddigital.com/opinion/amando-de-miguel/mas-etimologias-curiosas-46471/)). Del "falso señorito" pasó a designar a alguien que viste ridículo, por vestir elaborado cuando su apariencia es en realidad anticuada o vulgar.

Todas esas refencias (en incluso [esta otra](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?hortera), que también apunta al mismo origen) explican que el uso (o *abuso* del término forzándolo a esa evolución) es un *madrileñismo*.

Así que, **resumiendo**, de la etimología de *offertoria* que designa un platito que se usaba en tiendas, el nombre pasó a designar a los mozos de las tiendas que usaban dicho platito, de ahí a designar a alguien que viste bien pretendiendo darse un estatus social que no tiene para finalmente designar a alguien que pretende vestir elborado y sofisticado y en realidad viste mal (anticuado o vulgar).