# ¿Cómo llegó "botones" a usarse para referirse a un ayudante joven (mozo de hotel)?

Tags: etimología

De acuerdo a la RAE, un "botones" es

> [botones](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5zsZgf2)
>
> 1. m. y f. Persona joven que sirve en hoteles y otros establecimientos para llevar los recados u otras comisiones que se le encargan.

¿Por qué se les designa de esta manera a estos ayudantes?

En principio, de forma parecida a lo aprendido en [¿Por qué “hortera” es, en Madrid, el apodo del mancebo de ciertas tiendas de mercader?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19127/5481), donde vimos que se llamaba "horteras" a los ayudantes de la farmacia porque manipulaban una balanza u [horterilla](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/19136/5481), pensé que su nombre venía de manipular los botones del ascensor, pero la persona que manipula el mecanismo del ascensor tiene un nombre distinto:  [ascensorista](http://dle.rae.es/?id=3vqafHE)

> 1. m. y f. Persona que tiene a su cargo el manejo del ascensor.

Podría ser también por los botones del distintivo uniforme que usan los botones, pero otros muchos empleados llevan uniformes variopintos.

¿Cómo llegaron estos ayudantes de hotel (u otros establecimientos) a recibir ese nombre?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Efectivamente, parece que es por los botones de su indumentaria.

El primer diccionario que recoge la palabra es el *Alemany y Bolufer* de 1917, que dice:

> Por las tres hileras que suelen adornar la chaquetilla de su uniforme.

Y el DLE en su edición de 1936 confirma:

> De *botón* por los que lucen en su vestido.

Los casos del CORDE son todos del siglo XX (el más antiguo parece ser de 1918: "No había llegado el botones a la esquina cuando me dieron tu tele"). En la hemeroteca de la BNE se leen algunos más antiguos:

> Ahora, cualquier pelafustrán tiene un *botones* (antes *groom*).
>   De lo primero que se ocupan hoy los hombres de acción, ó en ejercicio de sus profesiones, es de adquirir un muchacho de doce ó catorce años, y vestirle de pies á cabeza, aunque la familia perezca de las prendas más necesarias para el trato de gentes.
>
> [Nuevo mundo (Madrid). 14/1/1897, página 6.](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0001263438&page=6&search=%22un%20botones%22&lang=es)

Interesante el nombre que le daban antes al botones. El texto se acompaña de la siguiente ilustración:

[image: Botones]

Que deja bastante claro el resalte de los botones en la chaqueta del uniforme.

Comment: Yo pensaba que también podría ser por los botones del ascensor. Si era el encargado de llevar a cabo la difícil tarea de recibir la orden "¡al quinto!" y traducirlo a la acción de pulsar el botón número 5 (ni Siri lo haría mejor), tiene sentido que fuera "el de los botones" y derivar a "el botones".

Answer (score 4):

Esa acepción de **botones** entró en el DLE de 1992 sin ninguna explicación, pero el [**DLE de 2001**](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/) recoge el origen en la acepción nº 16 de botón

> 16. (**Por los botones que suele lucir en su uniforme**). m. pl. Muchacho que sirve en hoteles y otros establecimientos para llevar los recados u otras comisiones que se le encargan.