# ¿Cuál es el origen de "pelagatos"?

Tags: etimología, historia, sustantivos, insultos

En el DRAE se explica que el significado de `pelagatos` es

> [**pelagatos**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SMVpqUW)
>
> 1. m. y f. coloq. Persona insignificante o mediocre, sin posición social o económica.

Buscando un poco cómo surgió el sustantivo `pelagatos` hay quien sugiere que viene de pelar un gato para comérselo. Sé que, durante algunos momentos de hambruna en España, hay quien recurrió a comer gatos para sobrevivir.

También hay quien dice que [el "gato" era un bolsón](https://espanol.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20101016145512AAQrPqo).

> [..] por hacerse con la piel de ese animal: *pelar el gato* era registrarlo hasta el fondo en busca de algún maravedí que pudiera haber quedado en su fondo.

Lo que no termina de parecerme en principio certero o riguroso.

¿Cómo se originó el sustantivo `pelagatos`?

Answer (score 4):

Pues lo mismo he dado con el origen de casualidad buscando la respuesta a otra cosa.

En su respuesta a [¿Cómo llegó “botones” a usarse para referirse a un ayudante joven (mozo de hotel)?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23189/5481) Charlie explica que [viene de los botones que llevaban en sus uniformes estos ayudantes](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/23193/5481) y en una de las citas incluye

> Ahora, cualquier **pelafustrán** tiene un botones (antes groom).

y me entró la duda sobre qué es un `pelafustan`.

En el [DLE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SMTCtrN) simplemente se recoge:

> **pelafustán, na**
>
> 1. m. y f. coloq. **pelagatos**.

mientras que [thefreedictionary](https://es.thefreedictionary.com/pelafust%C3%A1n) la incluye como

> **pelafustán, -tana**
>
> m. f. desp.Persona holgazana, perdida y pobretona.

y como sinónimo de "pelagatos".

Por otro lado, en el DLE "fustán" aparece como

> **[fustán](http://dle.rae.es/?id=IeSjA9o)**
>
> De origen incierto
>
> 1. m. Tela gruesa de algodón, con pelo por una de sus caras.

De acuerdo a [capsuladelengua](https://capsuladelengua.wordpress.com/2009/07/18/insultos/)

> es bueno saber que el insulto [**pelafustán**] tiene origen en el fustán, un tipo de tela pachoncito al que,  algunos desocupados, encontraban divertido dedicarse a arrancarle la lanosidad, de ahí que a estos tipos ociosos, sin oficio ni beneficio los llamaran pelafustanes.

y de ahí surgió `pelafustán` como sinónimo de "holgazán" o "pobretón" y por tanto "sin posición social". Desde luego la misma lógica se puede a "pelagatos", y que el término surgiese para referirse a una persona "socialmente insignificante" o "sin posición económica" ya que esta gente estaría (de forma figurativa o literal) rascando, despiojando o perdiendo el tiempo acariciando el pelaje de los gatitos.

Comment: Resulta curioso que hoy día el DLE considera equivalentes "pelafustán", "pelagallos" y "pelagatos", mas a principios del siglo XIX cada palabra tenía su significado propio con sus diferentes matices.

Comment: De hecho las iba a publicar como dos preguntas separadas, pero cuando encontré lo de "pelafustán" me pareció que respondía a esta duda (que me surgió a raíz de "pelafustán"). En cualquier caso, no me la doy por aceptada, porque como bien dices estas palabras han tenido otros matices o significados y sus orígenes pueden ser distintos. Lo mismo alguien puede encontrar otro origen para "pelagatos" que nada tenga que ver con "pelafustán" o "pelagallos".

Answer (score 1):

¿Podría venir de Juan Philagathos,, que fue antipapa en el año 997 La historia de su ascenso y de cómo acabó sus días podría dar bastante pie al significado actual

Answer (score 0):

Una pista al posible origen de "pelagatos" quizás se encuentre en la frase "me dieron gato por liebre". Es concebible que quien se ganara la vida durante tiempos de escasez o pobreza mediante esta práctica engañosa de negocio, empleara a alguien aun más desdichado para descuerar (pelar) la mercancía (la presunta liebre que en realidad era un gato). Esto colocaría al "pelagatos" en la parte más baja del escalafón socio-económico... Como dije, es solo una posible pista más a investigar.